# Phaser random generation of sprites in group

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a group where I want two types of blocks to be generated from left to right or vice versa. It is not really important; my randomization seems to work fine, but the problem is they only change if I refresh the game. But if I run it as it is, it will always be the same kind of block until I refresh. How can I fix this?

```
createOnebloque: function () {
    this.bloquecs = ["bloqueSprite", "bloquelSprite"]; ////// Here are the 2 sprites
    this.bloquesr = this.bloquecs[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)]; /// Here I randomize, but it only works when I refresh.
    this.bloque = this.game.add.group();
    this.bloque.createMultiple(5, this.bloquesr);
    this.bloque.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
    this.bloque.setAll('anchor.y', 0.5);
    this.bloque.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
    this.bloque.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);
},

makeBloques: function () {
    this.bloques = this.bloque.getFirstExists(false);
    if (this.bloques) {
        this.bloques.reset(1440, 1400);
        this.game.physics.arcade.enable(this.bloques);
        this.bloques.enableBody = true;
        this.bloques.body.immovable = true;
        this.bloques.body.velocity.x = -2000;
    }
}
```

This below goes on the create funtion:

```
this.game.physics.arcade.collide(this.bullets, this.bloque, this.collisionBulletBloque, null, this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from here:

```
this.bloquesr = this.bloquecs[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
```

You pick a random key once and use it from then on.

You can maybe rewrite the first function like this:

```
createOnebloque: function () {
    this.bloquecs = ["bloqueSprite", "bloquelSprite"];
    this.bloque = this.game.add.group();

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        this.bloque.create(this.bloquecs[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.bloquecs.length]);
    }
    this.bloque.setAll('anchor.x', 0.5);
    this.bloque.setAll('anchor.y', 0.5);
    this.bloque.setAll('outOfBoundsKill', true);
    this.bloque.setAll('checkWorldBounds', true);
}
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks so much let me test and come back thanks so much, I figure something like that but was unsure of how to proceed thanks.

Comment: Ok it kind of work, if I have 2 elements on my (this.bloquecs) it shows 1 and 2 repeatedly, but if I add 3 mores to make them 5 elements inside the array it only shuffles 3 of them, is this a common behavior?